# How to learn about http_interceptor using http package in multipart request

Tags: flutter, httpinterceptor

I am trying to implement `http_interceptor` for refreshing access token on expiry and retry http request. I had searched over internet but I had not found any useful links to work following is my code for multipart request in which I want to implement `http_interceptor`.

```
Future<void> postImage(BuildContext context, String imageType) async {
    var data = {"imagetype": imageType, "filename": imageType};
    Map<String, String> obj = {"attributes": json.encode(data).toString()};
    var flutterFunctions =
        Provider.of<FlutterFunctions>(context, listen: false);
    final url = Ninecabsapi().urlHost + Ninecabsapi().getvehicle;
    try {
      loading();
      var response = await http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(url))
        ..files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
            "imagefile", flutterFunctions.imageFile!.path,
            contentType: MediaType("image", "jpg")))
        ..headers['Authorization'] = token!
        ..fields.addAll(obj);
      loading();
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/http_interceptor#usage - it shows how to build and use your own custom interceptor

Comment: I had  studied that docs but I am not getting any idea to implement in above code

Answer (score 1):

Support for intercepting MultiPartForm data is available in https://pub.dev/packages/http_interceptor/versions/2.0.0-beta.6
Try using it.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to use Dio library to more easy handle the HTTP Request https://pub.dev/packages/dio

Comment: I am facing 500 error while using dio its works fine in http